# In a glm model, how to get independent variable results, given values for remaining independent and dependent variables?

Tags: r

I created a glm model in R, with 3 independent variables and a binary dependant one:

```
model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = train, family = binomial)
```

This is great to predict the outcome, given specific values for the independent variables, with a simple formula:

```
newdata <- data.frame(x1 = 10, x2 = 8, x3 = 5)
predict(model, newdata, type = "response").
```

But what about finding out x1, given that we want:

```
y = 1
x2 = 10 
x3 = 2
```

I've heard a for loop is a good option to get a list with possible value combinations. But don't know how to code it. 
Does any one know?
Or is it any built in function to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've got it:

```
x <- seq(1,100,by=1)
r <- vector(mode="numeric", length=100)

for (x1 in v) {
 r[x1] <- 1/(1+exp(-(CoefX1*X1+CoeffX2*10+CoeffX3*2)))
}

cbind(x,r)
```